# Maven project failed to build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, maven-3

I am new to Maven projects. I imported an existing Maven project to eclipse, then made a new configuration. I tried running the application then but the console shows

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:devserver (default-cli) on project helloworld: The plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException
```

I checked the link it showed. It suggested to update the build environment to the required Maven version. I searched for it but found out to make certain changes in pom.xml. But nothing worked. Can anyone tell me how to resolve the problem. My installed Maven version is `3.0.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to execute this plugin, you need maven version 3.1.0 at least. Install it from here (http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and after that check if it is correctly installed by executing following command in the command line:

`mvn -version`

Comment: I  have now installed Maven 3.2.1. But now I am not able to define an external Maven runtime. The Maven runtime configuration says "Target is not a Maven Home". I tried putting in i)/usr/share/maven, ii) /usr/bin/mvn, iii) /usr/bin/X11/mvn. But none is being accepted. It says " Target is not a Maven home"

Comment: Try /usr/bin/mvn/apache-maven-3.2.1 you need in this folder subfolders like bin, boot, conf and lib

Comment: Winkler Thanks for your answer, though it didn't solve the problem, it provided hints to do so. I looked for the maven directory that contained subdirectories like bin, boot, conf and lib. The directory was /usr/share/maven3. I tried it and voila, it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. The solution was easy. Eclipse was expecting the maven root to have `bin`, `boot`, `conf`, and `lib` sub-folders. That root folder was not (in my case) `/usr/local/Cellar/maven32/3.2.5`, but rather `/usr/local/Cellar/maven32/3.2.5/libexec`. Note the correct one is one folder deeper.

Answer (score 2):

for the poor soul who finds this thread because of this error in intellj...

I had my M2_HOME and maven environment all set to modern versions of maven and still got this error.  Search in your intellij preferences for "maven" and you'll see the default version *IntelliJ* uses is 3.0.5 - you'll see the version being set to "bundled" - set it to your maven download director and the app engine plugin will build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least version 3.1 and you have 3.0.5. All you should have to do is download a newer version of maven point your environment variable at it and you should be alright. The current version of maven is 3.2.5

https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: I have now installed Maven 3.2.1. But now I am not able to define an external Maven runtime. The Maven runtime configuration says "Target is not a Maven Home". I tried putting in 
i)/usr/share/maven,
ii) /usr/bin/mvn,
iii) /usr/bin/X11/mvn.
But none is being accepted. It says " Target is not a Maven home".