# Eclipse Maven 2 installation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am doing a Maven build in Eclipse where my project requires Maven 2.  My Maven runtime is set to embedded (3.2.1/1.5.1.20150109-1819).  How do I set the runtime to use Maven 2?

I tried setting a runtime installation by pointing to my Maven 2 installation, but that did not work.

[image]

[image: top level maven 2 path selected also does not work.]

[image]

Comment: add the path upto C:\tools\apache-maven-2.2.1

Comment: Tried that too, but I also get the 'Target is not a Maven Home.'

Comment: It seems the m2e plugin is not compatible with maven 2...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948235/maven-project-failed-to-build

Answer (score 6):

I pointed to libexec folder lying along bin, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the details of a similar issue, with the M2E plugin, below is the link.
https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg05131.html

It might help to upgrade the m2e version.
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/

Comment: I upgraded the m2e version to 1.6.2.20150902-0002, but get the same error.

Comment: I think they have removed support older versions of maven, 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438922

The have provided comments for it the bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have selected the wrong folder of maven. When you have unzipped the file directory will look like

[image]

you should have select directory pointed by red highlighter.

you should select the red highlighted folder. In your case you are pointing bin directory that's why it is creating problem.

[image]

Please do not forgot to click on your installed maven.
This has resolved my issue.